# Bluetooth LE still required when set "requried=false"

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have set my manifest to use bluetooth low energy feature and I want it to be optional, but when I try to update app in Google Play Store, it says I still require BTLE feature and it cuts my device range.

I've added `android:required="false"` param but it still doesnt work.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false"/>

<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false"/>
```

My aapt dump badge:

```
uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.bluetooth'
uses-feature: name='android.hardware.bluetooth_le'
uses-feature: name='android.hardware.camera'
uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera.flash'
uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.nfc'
uses-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.landscape'
uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.wifi'
uses-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.portrait'
```

On normal bluetooth feature it works, but on BTLE it doesn't.
I'm using Estimote SDK.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild project, because according your manifest le would be declared as not required

Comment: Cleaning project didn't help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your app uses Estimote SDK.  Library has declared feature as required.

From official site of [Manifest Merger tool](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Elements-and-Attributes-merging-process)

> `<uses-feature android:required>` - defaults to true. Merging with other attributes will use a OR merging policy since if any library requires the feature, the resulting application will require the feature.

Solution is to use `<tools:node="replace">` from [tools:node markers](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Markers)

> Replace the lower priority declaration with the annotated one.

You manifest would be next:

```
<manifest
    package="com.tivogi.so"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false"
        tools:node="replace" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false"
        tools:node="replace" />
   ....
</manifest>
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you~